# Php date Internationalization

Tags: php, date, internationalization

What I need is to get,  date like, `15 march 2014` but in my language. Is there any easy built-in way to translate date function that whenever I use

```
date("j F Y");
```

I get something like `15 march 2014` in my language?

BTW I need Azerbaijani translation. Maybe php already has built-in date-time languages.

## What I've done is:

1. Executed `sudo locale-gen az_AZ` and  `sudo locale-gen az_AZ.UT8` on ubuntu server
2. Tried `setlocale(LC_ALL, "az-AZ");` or `setlocale(LC_TIME, "az-AZ");` and all variations of az-AZ, aze, az_AZ on php file. No success!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`set_locale(LC_TIME, 'your locale')`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setlocale.php).

Here is an example for French: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setlocale.php#87038

Comment: I guess something like this: `set_locale(LC_TIME, 'az_AZ')`;

Answer (score 1):

You may use php_intl extension if it is on.

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) {
    exit ('IntlDateFormatter is available on PHP 5.3.0 or later.');
}    
if (!class_exists('IntlDateFormatter')) {
    exit ('You need to install php_intl extension.');
}

$fullDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'az_AZ',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE
);
$longDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'az_AZ',
    IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE
);
$shortDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'az_AZ',
    IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE
);
$customDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'az_AZ',
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    date_default_timezone_get(),
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'dd MMMM yyyy'
);

$datetime = new DateTime("2014-03-15 11:22:33");
echo $fullDateFormatter->format($datetime) . "\n";
echo $longDateFormatter->format($datetime) . "\n";
echo $shortDateFormatter->format($datetime) . "\n";
echo $customDateFormatter->format($datetime) . "\n";
```

The results are,

```
şənbə, 15, Mart, 2014
15 Mart , 2014
2014-03-15
15 Mart 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)(LC_TIME, 'your locale').